# Chrome for Android, Note 10.1 2014: Where is the share web address button?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm missing the three-dot button in the right end of the address bar.

I am not sure if it even was there in the first place, but on other Android tablets it is, I just checked at the local Samsung store.

Am I really supposed to share url's by copy-pasting into other apps? If so, is there an extension to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

On the Note 10.1, and most Samsung devices, you use the physical menu button to bring up the menu instead of the on-screen three-dots icon. You'll find **Share...** on that menu as usual.

[image]

Comment: You beat me to the answer. So, I'll just add the screenshot I made for this question. :)

Comment: It's a bit all over the place at the moment: the S4 does not have the 3 dot, but the S5 does in Chrome, some HTC (M7 and M8 (to be fair this has soft buttons anyway)) do have it but others don't. It's just down to the version and skin on the particular device. Samsung are moving away from the menu button and making it the 'recent apps' button on the S5 and I'd imagine this trend will continue.